# update from 0.6.3 to 0.7.6 becomes to crash without error

Tags: react-native

The main problem here is that I tried to update RN, but I was stuck on that and can't detect a real problem. No errors in console, I've just found something in Xcode

```
2022-12-23 20:38:48.824136-0600 OliveInvest[96591:229491] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-12-23 20:38:48.826635-0600 OliveInvest[96591:227282] [Intercom] ERROR - Tried to update user, but no user has been registered yet.
2022-12-23 20:38:48.828260-0600 OliveInvest[96591:227282] [Intercom] ERROR - Tried to send metrics, but no user has been registered yet.
2022-12-23 20:38:48.828990-0600 OliveInvest[96591:227282] -[NSNull code]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x110cae590
2022-12-23 20:38:48.836512-0600 OliveInvest[96591:227282] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull code]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x110cae590'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110a4a8cb __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fd47ba3 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110a59ad8 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110a4ed91 ___forwarding___ + 1431
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110a51088 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   OliveInvest                         0x0000000103174d27 RCTJSErrorFromCodeMessageAndNSError + 775
    6   OliveInvest                         0x00000001031749d0 RCTJSErrorFromNSError + 256
    7   OliveInvest                         0x0000000103105fd8 __41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke_4.110 + 152
    8   OliveInvest                         0x00000001035eca8f __51-[IntercomModule updateUser:resolver:failureBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 63
    9   Intercom                            0x0000000111c59af5 shouldRenderOnNewLine + 35719
    10  Intercom                            0x0000000111c23dde IntercomSDK_PINRemoteImageManagerSubclassOverridesSelector + 270363
    11  Intercom                            0x0000000111c24099 IntercomSDK_PINRemoteImageManagerSubclassOverridesSelector + 271062
    12  Intercom                            0x0000000111c1d138 IntercomSDK_PINRemoteImageManagerSubclassOverridesSelector + 242549
    13  Intercom                            0x0000000111c597f3 shouldRenderOnNewLine + 34949
    14  Intercom                            0x0000000111c42c81 IntercomSDK_PINRemoteImageManagerSubclassOverridesSelector + 396990
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001189e1d18 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001189e2f5b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001189f3d55 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1463
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001189f3790 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109a9b6f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109a4486 __CFRunLoopRun + 2482
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109a36f7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011c19c28a GSEventRunModal + 139
    23  UIKitCore                           0x000000013b54862b -[UIApplication _run] + 994
    24  UIKitCore                           0x000000013b54d547 UIApplicationMain + 123
    25  OliveInvest                         0x0000000102897220 main + 96
    26  dyld                                0x000000010f8b92bf start_sim + 10
    27  ???                                 0x00000002072fd310 0x0 + 8710509328
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6

-----------------------------------------

"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@gorhom/portal": "^1.0.14",
    "@growthbook/growthbook-react": "^0.9.0",
    "@intercom/intercom-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "4.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.10",
    "@rudderstack/rudder-sdk-react-native": "1.5.1",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.12.0",
    "appcenter": "^4.4.5",
    "appcenter-analytics": "^4.4.5",
    "appcenter-crashes": "^4.4.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "d3-scale": "^4.0.2",
    "d3-time": "^3.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "graphql-zeus": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lottie-ios": "3.4.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-animateable-text": "0.10.2",
    "react-native-appsflyer": "6.9.2",
    "react-native-auth0": "2.16.0",
    "react-native-biometrics": "3.0.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.5",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "10.3.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "3.4.6",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "2.5.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.8.0",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "1.14.0",
    "react-native-hash": "3.0.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.6.2",
    "react-native-mask-text": "0.13.1",
    "react-native-mmkv": "2.5.1",
    "react-native-modal": "13.0.1",
    "react-native-notifications": "4.3.3",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "2.1.0",
    "react-native-purchases": "4.5.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.13.0",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "3.0.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.18.2",
    "react-native-share": "8.0.1",
    "react-native-siren": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "5.2.4",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.6.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "2.1.5",
    "react-native-tracking-transparency": "0.1.2",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "1.3.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "yup": "0.32.11",
    "zustand": "3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/d3-scale": "4.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "16.11.12",
    "@types/react": "17",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.65.0",
    "@types/react-native-auth0": "^2.10.0",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "0.2.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/yup": "0.29.13",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.4.4"
  },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fqb5.gif)

Trying to replace project from the scratch,
and changing by info from https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Comment: Upgrading react-native has always been a pain for us, because both the JS and native code are changed, usually quite dramatically. We recently just upgraded from 0.65 to 0.70. We created a brand new project under 0.70, and moved the files little by little from the old project to the new until everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

I always erase the package.lock and the node_modules folder and reinstall everything.